# How to use \psVector as a replacement for \rlineto in drawing Theodorus' spiral?

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

Consider the following minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom[linecolor=green]
{
    \psline(1,0)
    \code{0 /Angle ED}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {
        \rlineto(!1 Angle 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt Atan add dup /Angle ED PtoC)
        \psline(0,0)(!!CP)
    }   
}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5) 
    \psset{linecolor=blue}
    \psline(1,0)    
    \pstVerb{/Angle 0 def}%
    \psStartPoint(1,0)
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {
        \psVector[arrows=-](!1 Angle 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt Atan add dup /Angle ED PtoC)
        %\psline(0,0)(!!CP)
    }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Explanation

There are 2 approaches:

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom[linecolor=green]
{
    \psline(1,0)
    \code{0 /Angle ED}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {
        \rlineto(!1 Angle 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt Atan add dup /Angle ED PtoC)
        \psline(0,0)(!!CP)
    }   
}
\end{pspicture}
```

produces

[image]

and

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5) 
    \psset{linecolor=blue}
    \psline(1,0)    
    \pstVerb{/Angle 0 def}%
    \psStartPoint(1,0)
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {
        \psVector[arrows=-](!1 Angle 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt Atan add dup /Angle ED PtoC)
        %\psline(0,0)(!!CP)
    }
\end{pspicture}
```

produces

[image]

### Question

What is wrong in the second method and how to fix it? I still want to use `psVector` so please don't throw it in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `\psVector` macro, the coordinate is evaluate two or three times, which redefines `Angle` each time with different values. If you want to stick with `\psVector`, you must move this definition to a separate macro call. Also, `\psVector` doesn't define a currentpoint, so that `CP` is undefined. For this you can use the coordinates `cp.X` and `cp.Y`, which get defined:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5) 
    \psset{linecolor=blue}
    \psline(1,0)    
    \pstVerb{/Angle 0 def}%
    \psStartPoint(1,0)
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {
        \psVector[arrows=-](! 1 Angle 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt atan add PtoC)
        \pstVerb{Angle 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt atan add dup /Angle exch def }%
        \psline(0,0)(! cp.X cp.Y)
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Simplification

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5) 
    \psset{linecolor=blue}
    \psline(1,0)  
    \pstVerb{/Angle 0 def}
    \psStartPoint(1,0)% <--- why is % needed? 
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {% <--- why is % needed?
        \pstVerb{Angle 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt atan add  /Angle exch def }
        \psVector[arrows=-](! 1 Angle PtoC)
        \psline(0,0)(! cp.X cp.Y)
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why `tx@Dict` ?

Comment: @Herbert For `Atan`. But I guess using only `tx@Dict begin Atan end` would be better, as it would keep a single `Angle`.

Comment: `atan` doesn't need it. It is for `ED`, but that can be `exch def`. And by the way `atan` exists on all PS level.

Comment: @Herbert I know, but not `Atan`, which is what CodeMocker uses.

Comment: yes, but nobody really needs `Atan` it exists only for some historical reason.

Comment: @Herbert Ok, I see. I updated the answer.